# Panel.DefaultButton and login button

Tags: asp.net

i have two form and each form has button , i have abstracted them by two panel so when enter key in each panel pressed , proper button will send .
in one panel i have login form

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlRegistered" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLoginButton">
    <LayoutTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="btnLoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1" OnClick="btnLoginButton_Click"  ClientIDMode="Static" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
 <asp:Panel>
```

but i get exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException

The DefaultButton of 'pnlRegistered' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.
```

Comment: Does this panel exist within a <template>, like in a Login control or a CreateUserWizard?  If so, the naming of DefaultButton will look different.

Comment: yes , it has  <LayoutTemplate> , i have set ClientIDMode of button to static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your panel inside `layouttemplate` of your login control

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlRegistered" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLoginButton">
            <asp:Button ID="btnLoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1"
                ClientIDMode="Static" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Comment: yes , bring `panel` tag to `LayoutTemplate` Solved Problem , thx

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the value of DefaultButton:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlRegistered" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLoginButton">
  <asp:Button ID="btnLoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" ValidationGroup="Login1" OnClick="btnLoginButton_Click"  ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:Panel>
```

EDIT: You can also set the DefaultButton in the code-behind, like so:

```
pnlRegistered.DefaultButton = btnLoginButton.UniqueID;
```